# Algorithm for exact URL pattern matching

Tags: java

I have a requirement where URL from REST web service needs to be matched with 500+ URL's in database and user needs to be authorized depending if he has access to that URL or not. 
The match should be best match and not first match.

for eg. the URL patterns would be like

/app1/abc/{userId}

/app1/pqr/*/text

/app2/*

/app2/xyz/{user_id}

/app3/pqr/*

if requested URL is /app2/xyz/123 it should match /app2/xyz/{user_id} and NOT /app2/*.

I am looking at java implementation or any ideas. I did look at Aho Corasick algorithm but i am not sure if it is best suited for this case.

Comment: Can try using a like query? Whatever part of the URL is dynamic you can skip and the remaining part you can fetch using a like query?

Comment: I do not want to used database for matching. There are several requests so most likely URLs would be in cache and i need an algorithm to do the pattern matching

Comment: if you use a cache, I would even go your Aho Corasick algorith (I didn't know the name, but had the same idea :) . You can store a tree in memory and travers it. But not a letter. but the whole url part should be stored in one node . Should be the fastest way.

Comment: Hello, please post what you have tried or thought about so far. StackOverflow will not write the whole solution for you.